# How to use collapse key in GCM

Tags: php, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notifications from PHP to android device.
Everything is working fine except I **dont want** messages to collapse .
Here is my code

```
   $random_collapse = rand(11, 100);
  $fields          = array(
                           'registration_ids'  => $receivers,
                           'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
                           'collapse_key'      => "{$random_collapse}", 
                           "time_to_live"      => 25000
                           );
```

Please suggest .

**EDIT**

I have used this also

```
   $fields          = array(
                           'registration_ids'  => $receivers,
                           'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
                           );
```

But still no  luck

Comment: How are you determining whether they were collapsed? How does your app handle the message from GCM? It's possible for the device to collapse the messages if you use the same `NOTIFICATION_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use the same notificationId on your android device.
It will create the effect of collapse key.

Collapse key is used only for delay and connection problems from the gcm to your device, when the device is connected again, gcm will only send the last collapse key received by the server. if the device is connected, you will receive several pushes even if they got the same collapse key(considering the next collapse key was sent when the old one already got received by the device).

if you want to do a whatsapp like collapses youll have to also manage them on your own device, in case the device will remain connected to the gcm and will receive those messages (as I said gcm cant pull back pushes you already showed on the client device IE same collapse key), so now you will use the same notificationId you gave to that notification.

Bottom line - Notification id is the "collapse key" of your(!) device.
You'll have to save the pair of them to know when to remove the old notification and when to show a new one.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages) gives an exhaustive use of collapsible messages. Have a look.